# HTTP Error 500.19 - ASP.NET MVC5 / Windows 2016 / IIS 10

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017, iis-10

I have an MVC web site developed in Visual Studio 2017. All works OK both on development and IIS7 / Windows 2008R2. The problem is that upon deployment to production Windows 2016 Server / IIS10 I get HTTP Error 500.19 complaining about the  part of my web.config.
Ideas anyone?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For all of you having the same issue: This turned out being an IIS configuration problem. Enable the feature below solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Install .NET Core Windows Server Hosting bundle. on Server